# chrome not displaying pdf right?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf, pdf-rendering

At first i thought TCPDF's GetStringWidth() was not working right, giving me the wrong width:

[----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]

I have some text like $txt = "hallo".

I've tried to get the strings width via the built in function GetStringWidth()
and then create a cell with the strings width.

```
// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('times', '', 20);
$pdf->SetCellPadding(0);

$txt = "hey i'm santa clause";
$width = $pdf->GetStringWidth($txt);

$pdf->Cell($width, $h=0, $txt, $border=1, $ln=0, $align='', $fill=false, $link='', $stretch=0, $ignore_min_height=false, $calign='T', $valign='M');

$pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

The created cell however is to short for it's content.
If I try the same with courier it works fine.

I think it's a measure of GetStringWidth not processing the font's width right, cause of Courier having the same width for each character, which works.

How can I get GetStringWidth() working

[----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]

Today I tried opening it with Firefox/Evince instead of chrome

Here's the result:[image]
Firefox is on the left, chrome on the right.

The generated PDF file is v. 1.7

Used version of chrome:

google-chrome-beta (41.0.2272.53-1)

What could have gone wrong here? Is it really chromes fault? Or am I missing somethign here?

Thanks

Comment: edited code snippet. it's now the whole document.
after adding $pdf->SetCellPadding(0) and setting $pdf->setFont() before $pdf->GetStringWidth() still no success.

Comment: created a ticket in the TCPDF bug forums. it was closed twice without any real suggestions. the author said the method is working fine and I was told to look for help in the regular TCPDF forum. did posted my issue there, too. no help so far

Answer (score 0):

You must try with replacing:

```
$pdf->Output("{$filename}.pdf", 'I');
```

with

```
$pdf->Output("{$filename}.pdf", 'D');
```